# Will I be able to modify two or more object instances using another object variable?

Tags: java

I am writing a simple two-player game console application, and I wanted to know if I can do the following below. I got confused with the whole Java pass-by-value/reference articles....

```
Player p1 = new Player("John");
Player p2 = new Player("Sam");
Player current = p1;

while(p1.life > 0 && p2.life > 0) {
    current.doSomething();
    if(current.name.equals(p1.name)) {
        current = p2;
    } else {
        current = p1;
    }
}
```

My apprehension is that it is the variable `current` that might get modified, but not `p1` or `p2`. It is those two instances that I want to modify. I just don't want to replicate an entire code block for each player, resulting in a very bulky if-else statement.

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding the answers provided so far, in this forum thread I drew some crude diagrams that might give you an idea: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/92744-what-am-i-doing-wrong.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apprehension is wrong.. `current`, `p1` and `p2` are all *references*. There are 2 instances and 3 references in your case. So, the *instance* pointed to by `current` can get modified and that will be reflected in `p1` or `p2` .

Answer (score 1):

That's ok. In Java, object variables are references. That means that the variable don't contains the values but is an indirection to the structure containing the values. So that, when `current=p1` is made, `current.life` or `p1.life` does have exactly the same effect. Object variables in Java are like firstname and nickname for you. You are the object, and anybody can refer to you using your firstname or any suitable nickname.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I be able to modify two or more object instances using another
>   object variable

**Yes you can !!!**

Java is **Pass By Value *Not* Pass By Reference** but in case of `Objects` Since they are at a single location in Heap Memory , So both the Reference points to Single Object unlike variables where copy has been created .

```
Website w=new Website("StackOverflow");
changeName(w);

public void changeName(Website w){<--- this w is now pointing to same Object passed to it , not making copies unlike variables

w.setName("StackExchange");
}
```

Since Object is passed So changes done to the state of Object will get reflected in `main(i.e caller)` function